# A better way to visualize API response normalized with "Normalizr"

Tags: javascript, json, normalizr

I have this normalized API response :

```
{
  "result": "123",
  "entities": {
    "articles": {
      "123": {
        "id": "123",
        "author": "1",
        "title": "My awesome blog post",
        "comments": [
          "324"
        ]
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Paul"
      },
      "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nicole"
      }
    },
    "comments": {
      "324": {
        "id": "324",
        "commenter": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any better ways to visualize/log/debug (an already normalized or while normalizing) a response other than `console.log()` used with `JSON.stringify()` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking - but if this is in the browser - its better to log the json object to console - rather than its stringified version - then you can navigate it in the console. You can also use breakpoints - and look at the structure in the debugger - and even make changes to it while your code is running.  or play with the data in the console - with other functions.

Comment: I think i found the answer, for those who are using *Normalizr* with *Redux*, using *redux-devtools* you can see a full normalized tree, once you pass it to reducer state. Other than that `console.log()` seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many NPM modules like [pretty-print-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-print-json) or [json-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-beautify) that can do this for you as well al libraries, although my favorite method for pretty-printing is still the console.log() paired with [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) because you can easily use the remaining arguments for beautify in console.

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) provides you a *replacer* and a *space* args:

1. The ***replacer*** allows you to keep in the stringified object the attributes that you want, so he finds in place the attribute and keeps it in the string;
2. The ***space*** defines the tabulation, is used to insert white space into the output JSON string for readability purposes only.